# data-edit="insertHTML someText" inserts text twice

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap wysiwyg editor and have customized it using my own menu items. One of the menu items has the following:

```
<li><a data-edit="insertHTML *|Name|*">Name</a></li>
```

When that menu item is clicked, the text "*|Name|*" is inserted twice into the text area.  So I get:

*|Name|* *|Name|*

Any ideas on how to get around this or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue, it looks like it tries to mimic html tags by adding two of them and placing the cursor in the middle. You probably didn't come up with a solution (or didn't bother to post here after asking this question). looking for an insert Text alternative for this :(

Comment: Changed it from "insertHTML" to "insertText" and it works better.